# iOS Swift App won't receive Push Notification sent by Parse Server

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, parse-server

I've followed tutorials online to try and set up push notification functionality in my app. I followed all of their steps, but I still cannot receive a push notification on my device once I send it from the dashboard.

Here is what I did:

1) Create Bundle ID, Provisioning Profile, and SSL Certificate on Apple Developer, all integrated into the app and server, and registered with my hardware development device. (All were of type iOS Development, NOT Distribution/Production)

2) Necessary functions set up in my `App Delegate`, such as `func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData)`

3) Installation ID successfully created of device on Parse Server.

4) Edit in Info.plist to set my bundle ID in accordance to the one with Push enabled on Apple Developer site.

5) Provisioning profile set in Build Settings and General, under Project and Target

6) Under Targets > MyApp > Capabilities, Push Notifications is turned ON

7) Download app from Xcode straight to a hardware test device.

8) Logged in test user on app.

9) App is open and running on device.

10) Send Push from dashboard.

11) Device does not receive notification, and dashboard says: Pushes Sent: 0

Am I missing anything? After all of this, my app still does not receive notifications.

Answer (score 0):

for testing in device you have to create production certificate. you can not use development certificate